# Does google speech api handle a bilingual audio stream

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to get text from an audio stream in which two languages are being spoken? For example, a recording in which one person is speaking French and another person is translating it into English.

Answer (score 0):

Speech-to-Text offers a way for you to specify a set of alternative languages that your audio data might contain. When you send an audio transcription request to Speech-to-Text, you can provide a list of additional languages that the audio data might include. If you include a list of languages in your request, Speech-to-Text attempts to transcribe the audio based upon the language that best fits the sample from the alternates you provide. Speech-to-Text then labels the transcription results with the predicted language code.

In this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-languages#speech_transcribe_multilanguage_beta-python) you could find some implementations like the described below:

```py
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech

client = speech.SpeechClient()

speech_file = "resources/multi.wav"
first_lang = "en-US"
second_lang = "es"

with open(speech_file, "rb") as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=44100,
    audio_channel_count=2,
    language_code=first_lang,
    alternative_language_codes=[second_lang],
)

print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)

for i, result in enumerate(response.results):
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]
    print("-" * 20)
    print(u"First alternative of result {}: {}".format(i, alternative))
    print(u"Transcript: {}".format(alternative.transcript))
```